# How to determine whether to model GARCH effects over ARCH effects?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, model-selection, garch, volatility

Based on my understanding, we could determine whether or not to include ARCH effects, by checking the residuals of the mean corrected model (EX: ARMA model).  I know the difference between GARCH effects and ARCH effects. But I am having a difficult time to understand how to determine whether we need to use GARCH effects over ARCH effects?

Is there a way to do that? Or should we just compare different models using some information criteria to conclude that?

Is it something like, first fit a ARCH model. Then check the residuals. If the residuals still have some heteroskedasticity, then include GARCH effects?

Thank you

Comment: Different modelling goals require different model selection strategies. If you are interested in forecasting, information criteria and time-series cross validation are sensible choices.